# Forms authentication redirects back to login page unless the app pool is recycled

Tags: iis, authentication, asp.net

We have an asp.net web app that uses forms based authentication, and we are having an issue with IIS and authentication. You will be able to authenticate for, Im just going to guess here an hour, after that hour when you try to login it will just redirect back to the login page. We have found that if you manually recycle the app pool the problem goes away for about an hour again. I refer to time but it could also be how many people are trying to authenticate. I'm not sure if it has something to do with virtual memory or worker threads. if someone could help me with this problem I would be very grateful.